# Should autosuggest input have type="text" or type="search"?

Tags: html, autocomplete, w3c, autosuggest

Are there any w3c recommendations regarding having `type="text"` vs `type="search"` on an `<input>` field of an autosuggest/autocomplete component?

[Example of autosuggest component](http://moroshko.github.io/react-autosuggest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because an `input` element offers autosuggest/autocomplete does not mean that it should have to use one of these two states, Text or Search. Autosuggest/autocomplete could, of course, also be offered for other states (like Number, URL etc.).

Unfortunately, HTML5 does not really *define* what the [Search state](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#text-%28type=text%29-state-and-search-state-%28type=search%29) represents. However, it notes:

> The difference between the Text state and the Search state is primarily stylistic: […]

So if you refer to it as "search field", if it would not be confusing for your users if user agents display it with a search icon or similar, and if, well, it lets users *search* something, then using the Search state makes sense.